# how to compare and apply changes in toad for mySQL

Tags: mysql, toad

Maybe I am blind - 
but after comparing the two DB (tools compre - schema compare ) I want to execute the changes so that db number 2 will be like db number 1 . How do I do apply the changes? 
10x

Comment: There is no generic answer for this. You can compare Facebook's database to eBay's, but there is no way to apply some change to turn a social network into an auction database. That's probably more of a gap than between your two databases, but there could just as easily be differences that you can't resolve automatically.

Comment: thanks. it seems like it is possible technically. let's say I execute the script of all the different object

Comment: sorry (continuing) from db one to db 2 . it's like i am doing an export and import of tables (I usually do it in mysql query browser) . I would expect that the TOAD tool , after discovering the different object - will allow me to export and import (via create or delete ) then changed objects from one db to another. (I know foreign key could be an issue, but  mysql query browser can handle them with export import tables)

Answer (score 3):

TOAD's schema compare utility does provide the automation of creating a script to apply the changes. After you run the compare you should be on a tab named "Results". If you look at the tabs there should also be one called "Sync Script" that shows the script to apply the changes.

Unfortunately you need to have bought the top-of-the-line license to be allowed to save this script. It is a teaser for the rest of us with only the print button enabled.

Of course, if you had a virtual printer driver that actually dumped to a file .... like a pdf file converter implemented as a printer driver.... well then you might be on to something......

Comment: Hi, I don't have a "results" tab. the results appear on an "untitled" tab. above it I see a disabled "synchronize" button